# By default open ion-fab-list

Tags: angular, ionic3, floating-action-button

I need top open ion-fab-list open by-default when the ionic page loads.

Please provide some help.

I have tried following solutions but did not work:

**1. write (click) event on fab-button in .html and call event from .ts.**

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.calculateButtons();
}

calculateButtons() {
  // buttonList list populated code
  this.fabButtonClicked(); 
}
fabButtonClicked() {
  console.log('Fab Button clicked.');
}
```

```html
<ion-fab bottom right #fab class="space-fab-list">
      <button ion-fab #fabBtn mini class="fab-button" [disabled]="!isButtonsFound" (click)="fabButtonClicked()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
      <ion-fab-list side="top" class="spaces-side-list">
      <button ion-fab *ngFor="let buttonObj of buttonList" class="button-fab-object" (click)="doSomthing(buttonObj)">buttonObj.title</button>
      </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

**2. Call setActiveLists method of FabContainer class**

Issue: Using this solution ion-fab-list is opened by-default but buttons are not populated from *ngFor. Empty fab-list opened.

```js
@ViewChild('fab') fabElement: FabContainer;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.calculateButtons();
}

calculateButtons() {
  // buttonList list populated code
  this.fabElement.setActiveLists(true);
}
```

This solution did not work for me.

Please help me to solve this issue.

**Dynamically generate buttons into ion-fab-list:**
Button list fetched from web-service

```js
<ion-fab bottom right #fab class="space-fab-list">
  <button ion-fab #fabBtn mini class="fab-button" ><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
  <ion-fab-list #fabList side="top" class="side-list">
      <button ion-fab class="space-fab-button home" (click)="openHome()">Home</button>
      <button ion-fab *ngFor="let button of buttonList" class="fab-button" (click)="doSomething(button)">{{ button.name }}</button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

Thanks,
Punita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion. I have solved this issue using ChangeDetectorRef.

call detectChange() method before setActiveLists() method execute

```js
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.fabElement.setActiveLists(true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here it is,

**Component side :**

```
import { FabContainer } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild('fab')fab : FabContainer;

ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.fab.toggleList();
}
```

**Template side :**

```
<ion-fab top right edge #fab>
    <button ion-fab mini ><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
    <ion-fab-list>
        <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
        <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open)**

---

Working with Dynamically generate buttons into ion-fab-list also:

**Component side :**

```
//Logic is same as above
buttonList = [
    { name : '1'},
    { name : '2'},
    { name : '3'},
    { name : '4'},
    { name : '5'},
]
```

**Template side :**

```
<ion-fab bottom right #fab class="space-fab-list">
  <button ion-fab #fabBtn mini class="fab-button" ><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
  <ion-fab-list #fabList side="top" class="side-list">
      <button ion-fab class="space-fab-button home" (click)="openHome()">Home</button>
      <button ion-fab *ngFor="let button of buttonList" class="fab-button" (click)="doSomething(button)">{{ button.name }}</button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open2)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it does not work for me. I am adding dynamic buttons to fab-list using *ngFor. The list is open but button inside ion-fab-list don't append 'show' class. Therefore buttons inside fab-list not displaying. if I manually do inspect button and edited class with 'show' then button show in list.

Edited post with my latest fab-list code.

Comment: @Punita, its alos working with dynamic buttons , https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open2

Comment: I have tried 

this.fabElement.setActiveLists(true);
and 
this.fabElement.toggleList();

both methods, but buttons do not display.

by buttons list are fetch from webservice

Comment: yes,

solved issue using this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
before this.fabElement.setActiveLists(true) method call.

Comment: @Punita , please check updated demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open2 , you can also do that

Comment: There are calling two APIs one-by-one because the first API is depending on first API's response. Also, lots of data coming from API then parsing and then displaying inside fab-list's button. therefore may. Maybe because of that 'show' class is not updated properly without ChangeDetector.

Comment: Then you should put the code once data is available from WS for fab-list.

Comment: Yes, i am doing same. After API's data fetched and parsing is done then after calling method this.fabElement.setActiveLists(true). Dynamic buttons are populated properly in HTML using *ngFor. But 'show' class is not getting append on list's button. The list is opened and fab-button is also changed from plus to cross, but list's buttons are not displayed.

Comment: Put that code block inside `setTimeout()` as I have did in demo it will work 100%.